# [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: c++, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2012, odbc

I am trying to connect SQL Server in C++ using below code but i am getting the same error "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified"

```
SQLHANDLE sqlenvhandle;    
SQLHANDLE sqlconnectionhandle;
SQLHANDLE sqlstatementhandle;
SQLRETURN retcode;

do
{
    if(SQL_SUCCESS!=SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &sqlenvhandle))
        break;

    if(SQL_SUCCESS!=SQLSetEnvAttr(sqlenvhandle,SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0)) 
        break;

    if(SQL_SUCCESS!=SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlenvhandle, &sqlconnectionhandle))
        break;

    SQLWCHAR retconstring[1024];
    switch(SQLDriverConnect (sqlconnectionhandle, NULL, 
        (SQLWCHAR*)"DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=(IPADDRESS\\SQLEXPRESS);DATABASE=test;UID=sa;PWD=abcd$1234;",
        SQL_NTS, retconstring, 1024, NULL,SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT))
    {
    case SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO:
        //show_error(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlconnectionhandle);
        retcode = 0;
        break;
    case SQL_INVALID_HANDLE:
    case SQL_ERROR:
        //show_error(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlconnectionhandle);
        SQLWCHAR sqlstate[1024];
        SQLWCHAR message[1024];
        if(SQL_SUCCESS == SQLGetDiagRec(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlconnectionhandle, 1, sqlstate, NULL, message, 1024, NULL))
        {
            retcode = -1;
            break;
        }
    default:
        break;
    }

    if(retcode == -1)
        break;

    if(SQL_SUCCESS!=SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, sqlconnectionhandle, &sqlstatementhandle))
        break;

    if(SQL_SUCCESS!=SQLExecDirect(sqlstatementhandle, (SQLWCHAR*)"select * from testtable", SQL_NTS))
    {
        //show_error(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, sqlstatementhandle);

        break;
    }
    else
    {
        char name[64];
        char address[64];
        int id;
        while(SQLFetch(sqlstatementhandle)==SQL_SUCCESS)
        {
            SQLGetData(sqlstatementhandle, 1, SQL_C_ULONG, &id, 0, NULL);
            SQLGetData(sqlstatementhandle, 2, SQL_C_CHAR, name, 64, NULL);
            SQLGetData(sqlstatementhandle, 3, SQL_C_CHAR, address, 64, NULL);
        }
    }
}
while(FALSE);
SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, sqlstatementhandle );
SQLDisconnect(sqlconnectionhandle);
SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlconnectionhandle);
SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, sqlenvhandle);
```

Current configuration is below:

- SQL Service is running.
- TCP/IP is also Enabled.
- System DNS Name is Set to "SQL Server" in ODBC.
- ODBC Source administrator target is "%windir%\System32\odbcad32.exe".
- Tried to replace connection string with IP Address and added port 1433 also.

but getting same error for all these settings.

Please let me know if i am missing anything or do i need to change my connection string or if there is any other way to connect SQL Server in C++.

Answer (score 0):

I have just added the _T in the connection string argument and it worked.

```
(SQLWCHAR*)_T("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=(IPADDRESS\\SQLEXPRESS); 
DATABASE=test; UID=sa;PWD=abcd$1234;")
```